# In Ember.js,how do you traverse the object inheritance tree using super()?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

If I have the following:

```
var ObjectA = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    document.write('init object A<br>');
  }
});

var ObjectB = ObjectA.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    document.write('init object B<br>');
  }
});

var ObjectC = ObjectB.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    document.write('init object C<br>');
  }
});

var myobj = ObjectC.create();
```

How do I make it so that ObjectC's init() method does not call ObjectB's init method?

http://jsfiddle.net/QYKb3/

Comment: It seems like you shouldn't be using inheritance if you don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by raycohen in #emberjs.  Of course the answer was simple, and simply involved calling ObjectA's prototype:

```
ObjectA.prototype.init.call(this);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QYKb3/1/